# How does a column of zeroes affect the nullity of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Say there is some 4 x 5 matrix A. Its reduced row echelon form has three "leading 1's" and has a column of zeroes as well as a row of zeroes.

The rank of the matrix, as I have understand it, would be 3 for this particular matrix as that is the dimension of the row space and the dimension of the column space.

However, I am unsure of what the  nullity of this matrix should be. According to my textbook, the nullity of some m x n matrix would be the number of parameters in the general solution Ax = 0. As it turns out, there is only one parameter in the general solution of A. So by the textbook's definition, the nullity of A would be 1.

But my professor has also mentioned the rank-nullity theorem, and that for any m x n matrix A the following equation holds true:

$$rank(A) + nullity(A) = n$$

where n is the number of columns in the matrix. If I am to acknowledge the column of zeroes in the 4x5 matrix, then nullity(A) = 5 - 3 = 2. This is a different result from that of the textbook's definition.

I believe I am misunderstanding something here about how I should regard columns of zeroes in the matrix. Do I account for them in determining the nullity of my matrix? Or are they to be ignored when calculating nullity? My intuition is that I should ignore them, but my intuition has often failed me in mathematics.

Comment: “As it turns out, there is only one parameter in the general solution of A” - this can’t be the case, there will be two free parameters

Comment: @Federico Oh, I see the error in my work. There are indeed two free parameters. So would that mean the answer to my question that columns of zeroes matter when determining rank and nullity of a matrix would be yes? i.e. a 4x99 matrix with 3 leading 1's and 95 columns of zeroes would have a rank of 3 and nullity of 96 whereas that same matrix but with an additional column of zeroes added onto the righthand side to make it 4x100 would have a rank of 3 but a nullity of 97?

Comment: Yes, column of zeros matter as much as any other column. Your example is correct